# Enforcing Server DateTime on remote client machine

Tags: datetime, timezone

I have two hosts: Server and a Client which are running on different Time Zones.
The server is sending the client an expiration date (DateTime) which the client should be enforcing.
Enforcing means that I need to exit my software when this DateTime exceeded the client's local time.

I need to know what is the DateTime format the server should be sending the client ?
How the client should be translating this time to its local time wiithout being vulnerable to TimeZone differences, 
And:
I also need to ensure that client clock rewind will not cheat calculation and server time will still be imposed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both your server and your client should communicate timestamps in terms of [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).  Doing so eliminates any need to concern yourself with time zones.

To ensure the client will not "cheat", you will need to implement the [Network Time Protocol (NTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) in your client application, which will require a connection to the Internet.

Comment: What are my options in NTP is not available ?

Comment: There are NTP implementations for just about every programming language.  However, if you mean what are your options if there is no Internet connection available?  Sorry, but then you are out of luck.  Without *some* accurate source of time, the goal is not achievable.